# jshint ignore:line with Eclipse issue

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, jshint, nodeclipse

When applying `jshint ignore:line` comment to suppress JSHInt `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='` for a line

```
} else if (argv[2]=='install'){ // jshint ignore:line
```

I got error sign on the left ruler (instead of warning)

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Bad option: 'ignore'
- Expected '===' and instead 
 saw '=='
- ES5 option is now set per 
 default
```

That is applying the config makes it even worse.

`jshint ignore:line` config is taken from JSHint Documentation http://www.jshint.com/docs/

JSHint Integration v0.9.9 comes with JSHInt 2.1.10 , see https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse

**Is this JSHint bug or this option was not implemented in 2.1.10 ? [JSHint Integration](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/) bug?**

Of course I can configure `"eqeqeq" : false` in `.jshintrc` inside project, but my intention is to only disable it for 1 line.

Comment: Not supported: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.2.0

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - He says `2.1.10`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: it was only added in 2.2, can't be screwed right now to write a proper answer.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - I thought you were saying it was not supported in 2.2.0, my bad :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Qantas for pointing out.

`jshint ignore:line` is [introduced since 2.2.0](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.2.0)

> JSHint now allows you to ignore parts of the file or specific line using the special /*jshint ignore */ directive.